# QGIS Processing Toolbox: otb provider XML

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to integrate an OTB application into the processing toolbox.

MANUALLY created a XML file for it but get : Could not open OTB algorithm: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\otb\description\BuildingExtraction.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\otb\OTBAlgorithm.py", line 142, in defineCharacteristicsFromFile
the_result = map(self.adapt_list_to_string,rebu)
File "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\otb\OTBAlgorithm.py", line 93, in adapt_list_to_string
a_list[3] = -1
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Here is the file:

```
    <root>
<key>BuildingExtraction</key>
<exec>otbcli_BuildingExtraction</exec>
<longname>Building extraction</longname>
<group>Segmentation</group>
<description>Classify segments into building/not building classes</description>  
<parameter>
  <parameter_type source_parameter_type="ParameterType_InputVectorData">ParameterVector</parameter_type>
<key>train</key>
<name>Training set</name>
<description>at least 10 buildings and 10 non buildings.</description>    
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameter_type source_parameter_type="ParameterType_InputVectorData">ParameterVector</parameter_type>
<key>data</key>
<name>Set to classify</name>
<description>From cartographic mapping.</description>    
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameter_type source_parameter_type="ParameterType_OutputVectorData">OutputVector</parameter_type>
<key>out</key>
<name>Output Vector</name>
<description>Output VectorData.</description>
<hidden />
</parameter>
<parameter>
<parameter_type source_parameter_type="ParameterType_String">ParameterString</parameter_type>
<key>modelname</key>
<name>Output SVM model</name>
<description>Output SVM model name prefix.</description>
</parameter>
</root>
```

Basically: 2 vector data shapefiles as input, 1 name for the output model and 1 output vector data for results.

What am I missing?